# Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'IAuthenticationService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section

Tags: c#, wcf, error-handling

I tried creating a simple WCF application, I haven't changed any of the existing default configurations. I have tried consuming the service using the `TestClient` generated by using `svcutil.exe`. It is showing an error message `"Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'IAuthenticationService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element."` I tried putting endpoint to localhost:port number/test.svc but its showing the same error.

this code is being shown after i execute the web test client. I couldnt trace out the error after searching for long hours over internet

Here is my testClients clientdll.config

```xml
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="wsHttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                    receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
                    transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                    allowCookies="false">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                        enabled="false" />
                    <security mode="Message">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                            algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:2490/AuthenticationService.svc"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding"
                contract="IAuthenicationService" name="wsHttpBinding">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: include your client app.config in post please

Comment: @MarvinSmit i have edited posting the config which i got after executing the test client.

Comment: The error refers to a service contract "IService1" not being there. Looking at your config, thats exactly what the problem is. You only configure an endpoint for "IAuthenicationService".

Comment: No i have configured the same, i have tried creating two project one in real time and another for execution test, both of them not working after much testings@MarvinSmit

Comment: not problem with the IService1 @MarvinSmit

Comment: to quote the OP "It is showing an error message "Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'IService1' in the ServiceModel client"

Comment: tried the same with both IService1 in one project and IAuthenticationService in another project. IService1 wtih all the default conditions they have given and i havent modified anything in it. IAuthenticationService with my endpoint address of localhost @MarvinSmit

Comment: *"I tried creating a simple WCF application, i havent changed any of the existing default configurations."*  By default, SOAP request over http in WCF (.NET 4.0 and later) use `basicHttpBinding`.  Try switching the binding in your client config to `basicHttpBinding`, or specify `wsHttpBinding` as the protocol for the http scheme in your service's configuration.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try removing the end points there and use

```
 compilation debug=true
```

in web.config. then after trying

```
svcutil.exe http://your_wsdl
```

you will generate an output.config. Try putting in servicemodel nodes  replacing your client website or application with the output.config service model. It will work

Answer (score 6):

> This might be because no configuration file was found for your
>   application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract
>   could be found in the client element.

The name of the binding or contract will be wrong. You confing needs to look something like

```xml
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Binding1" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://foo" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Binding1" contract="Service.MyService" name="MyService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Make sure the `bindingConfiguration` matches the `binding name`. In the above example `Binding1`