# Could not find default endpoint element that references contract in the ServiceModel

Tags: c#, wcf

```
PmtSl.AccessMgtClient = new PaymentProcessing.UI.Worker.MvvmSample.AccMgt.AccessManagementServiceClient();
```

Config file

```
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
    To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
    Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
    -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

While connecting to the serice, I am getting the following exception:

> Could not find default endpoint element that references contract
>   'AccMgt.IAccessManagementService' in the ServiceModel client
>   configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was
>   found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching
>   this contract could be found in the client element.
>
> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   PaymentProcessing.UI.Worker.MvvmSample.dll but was not handled in user
>   code
>
> Additional information: Could not find default endpoint element that
>   references contract 'AccMgt.IAccessManagementService' in the
>   ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no
>   configuration file was found for your application, or because no
>   endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client
>   element.

Comment: Add your web.config code here

Comment: i have added my web config file of service

Comment: i'm using wpf application and wcf service

Comment: Here is the solved links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659210/could-not-find-default-endpoint-element-that-references-contract-iauthenticatio and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583220/could-not-find-default-endpoint-element-that-references-contract

Comment: Thank you I think this will be useful..

Comment: When you post code, please format it first!!